# How to create number +1 from the previous sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to copy single sheet to multiple sheets in the same workbook with macros,I know how to do it but I still have further question.

I am using formula:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
x = InputBox("How many copies you want?")
For numtimes = 1 To x
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Next
End Sub
```

Let say that I copy single sheet into new 5 sheets, The sheets name will be:

```
Sheet 1 | Sheet 1 (2) | Sheet 1 (3) | Sheet 1 (4) | Sheet 1 (5) | Sheet 1 (6)
```

What I want is:

```
the formula in the "Sheet 1 (2)" Cell A1 is "='Sheet 1'A1+1" and 
the formula in the "Sheet 1 (3) cell A1 is "='Sheet 1 (2)'A1+1: and 
the formula in the "Sheet 1 (4) cell A1 is "='Sheet 1 (3)'A1+1: and
the formula in the "Sheet 1 (5) cell A1 is "='Sheet 1 (4)'A1+1: and
```

Or whatever the formula are, I just want that the next sheet cell A1 refer to number with +1 from the previous sheet. (Just like pages).

I want to know how to do it especially in excel 2003?

Answer (score 0):

On `Sheet 1 (2)` in `A1` enter

```
=SUM(Sheet 1!A1,1)
```

And respectively to other sheets.

For LibreOffice it would be

```
=SUM(Sheet 1.A1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this addition to your code:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer, tmpSheet As Worksheet
x = InputBox("How many copies you want?")
For numtimes = 1 To x
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
    After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Next
For y = 2 To x + 1
    Set tmpSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1 (" & y & ")")
    If y = 2 Then
        tmpSheet.Range("A1").Formula = "='Sheet1'!A1 + 1"
    Else
        tmpSheet.Range("A1").Formula = "='Sheet1 (" & y - 1 & ")'!A1 + 1"
    End If
Next y
End Sub
```